# Jquery Sorting By Price & Alphabetically

Tags: jquery, sorting

So I have this so far:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/De8Ku/1470/)

And I for the life of me cannot figure out why the price will not sort correctly? You will see that "6" appears at the end rather than the start.

Alphabetically works but no clue why price has issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a problem when sorting because of the parsing problem due the the dollar sign.
I modified your code like this and it worked

```
var vA = parseInt($(keySelector, a).text().replace("$",''));
        var vB = parseInt($(keySelector, b).text().replace("$",''));
```

Try this 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/De8Ku/1477/)

Answer (score 2):

It's because your sort function doesn't know that you want to treat $6 as "6" so it's treating it like a string and sorting it that way. This is crude, but will put you on the right track:

http://jsfiddle.net/De8Ku/1472/

Answer (score 1):

This one time I had to create a table sorter plugin in jQuery, and I had to go through the same problem you have now.
To be honest, I don't really remember how I solved that problem anymore, but I still have a fiddle of the code i finally used for my website if you're interested.

http://jsfiddle.net/bcnobel/WbWDm/

Comment: Thanks! Will have a play and see what comes of it - will be sure to post the correct code

Answer (score 1):

As it's sorting price as alpha style it is expected.

Please check this fiddle, I have associated sorting type with this

http://jsfiddle.net/De8Ku/1476/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/De8Ku/1479/